# Formula to dynamically calculate .slice() - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to dynamically render array elements into specified number of columns.

Given an array `const sessions = [10, 10, 5]` and `const trials = [1, 2, 3, ..., 25]` where sessions.length is the number of columns and trials is the data.

```
    <div class="column-1">
      {
          trials.slice(0, 10).map(t => {
            return <p>{t} seconds</p>
          }
      }
    </div>
    <div class="column-2">
      {
          trials.slice(10, 20).map(t => {
            return <p>{t} seconds</p>
          }
      }
    </div>
    <div class="column-3">
      {
          trials.slice(20, 25).map(t => {
            return <p>{t} seconds</p>
          }
      }
    </div>
```

In column 1, I would display the first 10 elements in `trials` because `sessions[0] = 10`. In column 2, I would display the next 10 elements in `trials` because `sessions[1] = 10`, and finally the next 5 items because `sessions[2] = 5`.

My ideal solution would be using something like this where I need to figure out how to calculate `x` and `y` based on `sessions`:

```
sessions.map((s, idx) => {
    <div class=`column-${idx+1}`>
      {
          trials.slice(x, y).map(t => {
            return <p>{t} seconds</p>
          }
      }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Create `x` outside the map, initialized to `0`, and then `trials.slice(x, x = x + s)`

Comment: I wasn't going to post an answer since that isn't really JS, and I don't know what language it is (maybe React or something?) but now I feel I should given the accepted answer, so I'll assume it  generally uses JS semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do to calculate the `x` and `y`.

```
sessions.map((s, idx, sessions) => {
   const x = sessions.slice(0, idx).reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0);
   const y = x + s;
   return (
      <div class=`column-${idx+1}`>
         {
            trials.slice(x, y).map(t => {
               return <p>{t} seconds</p>
            }
         }
      </div>
   )
}
```

* `sessions` in the first callback will be the sessions array. I used the `reduce` method to calculate the slice's start position.

* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: No, you really don't need to recalculate the values on every iteration. You're iterating anyway, so just have a variable that keeps a running total, like I show in the comment below the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a running total of the sum of `sessions` while you `.map()` the array.

```
let x = 0;

sessions.map((s, idx) => {
    <div class=`column-${idx+1}`>
      {
          trials.slice(x, x = x + s).map(t => {
            return <p>{t} seconds</p>
          }
      }
    </div>
}
```

---

If you don't like using the result of the assignment in the position of an expression, then use a second variable and do the calculation before the markup.

```
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

sessions.map((s, idx) => {
    x = y;
    y = y + s;

    <div class=`column-${idx+1}`>
      {
          trials.slice(x, y).map(t => {
            return <p>{t} seconds</p>
          }
      }
    </div>
}
```